# .DLL not found on login to Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

When one of our users logs onto a Windows Server 2008 R2 server with RDC, she receives the following 3 popups:

[image]

I can't find any mention of meray.dll, brape.dll or bryntb.dll on the web.

If I load msconfig on her RDC session, I can't see any mention of these in the Startup tab.  Would some items be hidden?  I loaded msconfig using my admin credentials.

How do we prevent these errors from opening on login?

Comment: It looks like your server (or the user, rather) is compromised. Random .dll names are characteristic of malware trying to execute on your machine.

Comment: @NathanC: What should I do?  Recreate the user account?

Comment: Start with that and see where that leads.